# Access to data using Google AdSense Management API - PHP

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, service-accounts, adsense-api

I'm trying to retrieve data from an AdSense account through the AdSense Management API.

I have successfully retrieved data using Google APIs Explorer when connected with my AdSense account.

I am now trying to get this data from a PHP script which will be run in a crontab.

My understanding is that I need a `Service account` which I created and I generated a json file.

The following code fails if I try to use the json file with two different errors :

1. if I use the setSubject with the owner of the AdSense account : 
   "error": "unauthorized_client",
   "error_description": "Client is unauthorized to retrieve access tokens using this method."
2. If I comment the setSubject : 
   "reason": "noAdSenseAccount",
   "message": "User does not have an AdSense account."

Code:

```
 <?php

require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';

putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=../conf/Mercury-testlpstats.json');

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();

$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly');

//$client->setSubject('AdTech@Lagardere-Pub.com');


$service = new Google_Service_AdSense($client);


$startDate = '2017-05-01';
$endDate = '2017-05-01';
$optParams = array(
     'metric' => array('INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS', 'EARNINGS'),
     'dimension' => 'DATE',
     'filter' => array('AD_UNIT_ID==ca-pub-XXXX:YYYY'),
     'useTimezoneReporting' => true
);

$report = $service->accounts_reports->generate('pub-ZZZZZ', $startDate, $endDate, $optParams);
```

**2nd attempt with OAuth**

I've created a OAuth account in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials/oauthclient/. When I check the AdSense API, my account appears in the list of authorized users in https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/api/adsense.googleapis.com/overview.

I've downloaded the corresponding JSON and changed my code but it still says:

- "insufficientPermissions" if I set $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
- "Login Required" otherwise

---

```
require_once '../../vendor/autoload.php';

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAccessType('online');
$client->setAuthConfigFile('/home/al1/lpstats/conf/client_secret_725834039890-klbuc13f8089rjh7eis439b93n7sqqfv.apps.googleusercontent.com.json');
$client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense.readonly');

$service = new Google_Service_AdSense($client);

$startDate = '2017-05-01';
$endDate = '2017-05-01';

$optParams = array(
     'metric' => array('INDIVIDUAL_AD_IMPRESSIONS', 'EARNINGS'),
     'dimension' => 'DATE',
     'filter' => array('AD_UNIT_ID==ca-pub-5035025648894332:3442683203'),
     'useTimezoneReporting' => true
);

$report = $service->accounts_reports->generate('pub-5035025648894332', $startDate, $endDate, $optParams);
```

Comment: The user you are authenticating with doesn't have an account you need to authenticate with a user who has an adSence account.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm trying to do when I use setSubject with the email of the AdSense account owner. Should I use something else than a service account ?

Comment: setSubject is used to impersonate a user when you are authenticating with a service account.    Make sure the service account has access to the users adsence account

Comment: I added the service account email to the AdSense user list and AdSense told me that an email had been sent to that Service Account email address. But I don't know how to retrieve mails from a service account email address.

Comment: I've updated my question with my failed attempt at using OAuth. So far, no success. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you have now changed the context of this question.  The question was about using a service account.  Which my answer shows you that it cant be done.    If you are switching to using Oauth2 and having issues with that then you should post a new question related to that code.

Answer (score 1):

> unauthorized_client

Means that the user you are authencating with does not have access to the Adsence Account you are trying to access.

**Service account support**

There are a number of Google APIs which don't support service accounts.  Most noticeably would be YouTube API which does not even have a way of sharing your account with another user.

There are others which will allow you to share your data with another user but require that the user in question respond to an email notification.    Blogger is one and Adsence is apparently another.

**Solution**

You will need to authenticate using Oauth2 using a user who has access to the adsence account in question.   Authenticate your code once save the refresh token and use the refresh token to request a new access token within your cron job.